# alternative model of a rational elliptic curve

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E : y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$ with  $a,b\in \Bbb Z$ be an elliptic curve.

If $(x, y) ∈ E(\Bbb Q)$ Prove $\exists \alpha, \beta\, \gamma \in \Bbb Z$ such that $x =
\alpha  /\gamma  ^2 , y = \beta  /\gamma  ^3$ with $(\alpha  \beta , \gamma) = 1$.

I don't see how to tackle this problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can also find a solution from "Rational Points on Elliptic Curves", chapter III.2. Let $x=m/M,y=n/N$ such that $\gcd(m,M)=\gcd(n,N)=1$ and clear denominators. Then show 1: $N^2\mid M^3$, 2: $M^2\mid N^2$, 3: $M^3\mid N^2$. This gives $M^3=N^2$, so $M,N$ must be of the form $\gamma^2,\gamma^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be a prime dividing the denominator of $x$. Suppose $p^r$ is the largest
power of $p$ dividing it. Then $p^{3r}$ is the largest power of $p$ dividing
the denominator of $x^3+ax+b=y^2$. This means that $p$ also divides the denominator of $y$, and if $p^s$ is the largest power of $p$ dividing
its denominator then $p^{2s}$ is the largest power of $p$ dividing
the denominator  of $y^2$. Therefore $2s=3r$ which means that $(r,s)=(2t,3t)$
for some positive integer $p$.

Likewise if $p$ does not divide the denominator of $x$ it cannot divide
the denominator of $y$.

So the denominators of $x$ and $y$ can be written as $p_1^{2t_1}p_2^{2t_2}\cdots p_k^{2t_k}$ and $p_1^{3t_1}p_2^{3t_2}\cdots p_k^{3t_k}$ respectively, therefore as $\gamma^2$ and $\gamma^3$ where $\gamma=p_1^{t_1}p_2^{t_2}\cdots p_k^{t_k}$.

Comment: Thank you. I think you consider all the fractions to be reduced?i.e the numerator and denominator are without common divisors

Comment: @PerelMan Naturally....